# jquery adding existing html element to var

Tags: jquery, dom

Any idea how can i insert the main_nav to the exact place?

```
var header_top ="<header><div>";
var main_nav = $('#nav').html();
var header_bot = "</header></div>";

var final_header = header_top + main_nav + header_bot;

$('body').prepend(final_header);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by exact place?

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: The main_nav doesn't appear inside <header><div>here</div></header>

Comment: Are you trying to move the main_nav?

Answer (score 2):

You have the order of `header` and `div` opening and closing tags mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
$("#nav").wrap("<header><div></div></header>");
```

This assumes that the `#nav` element is already positioned where you want it, so I didn't bother with the `prepend`. If you do need to move it to the beginning of the body:

```
$("#nav").wrap("<header><div></div></header>").prependTo($("body"));
```

Comment: So with that, i can use this? $('body').prepend($("#nav").wrap("<header><div></div></header>"));

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you need to move the element after wrapping it. I assumed the prepend in the question was only because you were creating a new element and needed to add it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to have all of the code in one variable, I'd suggest doing something like

```
var header = "<header><div>"+$('#nav').html()+"</div></header>";
$('body').prepend(final_header);
```

Comment: Sorry but i manually typed it here. Just to have an idea to what my problem is.